# Controlling a relay using a DHT22 on raspberry pi B model

Tags: python, relay, geany, adafruit

I am trying to create essentially a thermostat control using a DHT22 sensor. I would like to read the data from the sensor and using an if statement compare the sensor value to a set temperature value. If achieved the if statement would turn on a relay using a normally off outlet. Below is the code i have wrote in Geany programming to get a general idea of what i would like to do.

```
from time import sleep

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

import Adafruit_DHT as dht


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 

AC_1_GPIO = 17                              #sets relay to GPIO pin 17 for AC unit control

DHT_1_GPIO = 3

GPIO.setup(AC_1_GPIO, GPIO.OUT)             #sets up GPIO to be on or off based on condition

#GPIO.setup(DHT_1_GPIO, GPIO.OUT)                           #

humdtemp = dht.read_retry(dht.DHT22, DHT_1_GPIO)

Temp_Max = 32                                           #this is temperature maximum value for tent

#Humd_Max = 60                                          #this is relative humidity maximum value for 
#Humd_Min = 30                                          #this is relative humidity mininum value for 

while True:                                           #creates continuous loop

    if humdtemp > Temp_Max:                                     #compares sensor value to maximum 
# temperature value

        GPIO.output(AC_1_GPIO, GPIO.LOW)                #turns on AC unit using controllable relay

    elif humdtemp == Temp_Max:

        print ("Achieving 72 degree temperature")     #we need to select a temperature setpoint value

    else:
        GPIO.output(AC_1_GPIO, GPIO.HIGH)               #turns 'on' normally off relay
```

Comment: `dht.read_retry()` returns a tuple of humidity and temperature.  Comparing that tuple to an integer is utterly meaningless.  You should do something like `humid, temp = dht.read_retry()` so that you get the values in separate variables.

Comment: Hello, I was able to do that and it worked. Thank you for the help!